# error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string'

Tags: wpf, winforms, xaml, user-controls

I added wpf usercontrol to winform project.
However I failed compilation.

I got errors.
error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string'.

```
string abc = test.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("name");  
//type of test is Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Attachment  
//test.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty return dynamic.
```

I found the cause.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CustomControls"
                    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
                    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                    mc:Ignorable="d">
```

**xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CustomControls"** is the cause.
If **xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CustomControls"** is removed, I don't get error.

Why is that?

Comment: When you say "I added wpf usercontrol to winform project". Did you add all the wpf references to that project? In .net old that would be  Presentationcore etc in net core Microsoft.Windows.Desktop.App.WPF  Personally, I would put any wpf in a separate project and reference that if I really needed to stay with winforms. I'd rather have all winforms or all wpf in any given app though.

Comment: @Andy I added references for WPF controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find the cause, but I resolved it anyway.
I added explicit conversion.

```
string abc = (string)test.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("name");
```